# How to print DIN C4-size envelopes?

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, scrlttr2, envlab

I would like to print a DIN C4-size envelope with `FROMADRESS` and `TOADRESS` (according to DIN). But I haven't found a solution implemented already in `scrlttr2`. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Could you please link or explain the DIN specification? And do you insist on `scrlttr2` document class?

Comment: DIN C4: 324 mm x 229 mm, [look here](https://www.deutschepost.de//mlm.html/dpag/images/download/broschueren.Par.0381.File.pdf/automationsfaehige_briefsendungen_1_2005.pdf) on page 20.

Comment: DIN C4: 324 mm x 229 mm, basically it is divided in quarters. The upper left quarter = FROMADDRESS. It has no outer margins (left, top), FROMADDRESS starts in the left upper corner. The bottom right quarter = TOADDRESS. It is limited by outer margins (15 mm) to the right & bottom. TOADDRESS - First line starts in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 4):

Markus Kohm has published a solution at KOMA-script’s homepage: [\makelabels mit scrlttr2](http://www.komascript.de/mlabel.lco) (it's in English despite the German title). You may either define a special page in your letter, defining corresponding pseudo values. But you may also use the `mlabel.lco`, which introduce the `\makelabel`command from the standard letter class in `scrlttr2`. Then, you just have to define a label with the address at the correct places.

Have a look at the examples in the documentation to get some ideas. The envelope may be printed as a page of your letter.